# I can't add new account at myopenid.com - what should I do now?

Tags: openid

I wanted to change domain I'm using for OpenID at myopenid.com. To do this I registered new domain, selected it, chose *Add accounts* from menu, entered e-mail address and user name for the new account and clicked *Add accounts* button. After page reloaded I got confirmation saying *Sent invitation message to my e-mail address here.* However I haven't received any e-mail. There's an option to re-send an invitation which I tried a few times but with no result.

There's no support for MyOpenID users ([Unofficial community-powered support for
myOpenID](http://getsatisfaction.com/myopenid) is dead). I only managed to find this topic [myopenid - add user accounts fails](https://support.janrain.com/entries/20317633-myopenid-add-user-accounts-fails) at http://support.janrain.com but with no answer.

Has anyone had the same problem?
What should I do now?

Comment: Don't use an unsupported service, there's really nothing more to say, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I had a different problem with MyOpenID (OpenID logins were failing due to a bug in their implementation) and I finally contacted the company behind it through their Facebook account. They basically told me that the service is no longer supported.

Said that, once you've hit a bug in MyOpenID you're left with no options but switching to another provider.